How to Detect PC State (Unlocked, Sleep, Hibernate, Shutdown) in PowerShell Script?
I'm working on a PowerShell script where I need to ensure that it only proceeds if the PC (OS- Windows) is in an active state, meaning it's not locked, in sleep mode, hibernating, or shutting down. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to reliably check for these conditions within the script.
Here's what I need to accomplish:
Check if the PC is not locked.
Verify if the PC is not in sleep mode.
Ensure the PC is not in hibernation.
Confirm that the PC is not in the process of shutting down.
I've researched various PowerShell commands and functions, but I haven't found a comprehensive solution yet. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this in PowerShell? Any sample code or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

When in sleep mode and hibernation, your code will not be running.  No code on the computer is running, the computer, in both cases, goes into a suspend state where everything comes to a stop and it waits for a signal to wake up.  There might, I stress "might", be a way to detect if it is currently in the process of going into hibernation, sleep mode, or the powered off state.  But, if you know your code runs for 10 seconds, not sure how you can know if it going to enter one of those states in less than 10 seconds from now.

Is this Windows?  What ever can be done, will likely be unique to the OS you are running your code in.

I believe you can check the event log to see if a sleep or wake event is the most recent event.

You can use this answer as a starting point for getting the idle time of the computer.  You can use Powercfg to get the STANDBYIDLE and same should work for HIBERNATEIDLE.
